# What is the correct Dockerfile to install pyodbc on python:3.10.9-slim-buster image?

Tags: docker, pyodbc, python-docker

I have been using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline) guide for Debian 10.
I also needed install g++ for the pyodbc package to be installed.

I am using this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg g++ unixodbc-dev
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 

RUN exit
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

I am getting the error:

> Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
FROM python:3.10.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg g++ unixodbc-dev
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 

RUN exit
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

COPY /requirements.txt /  

COPY /odbc.ini / 
RUN odbcinst -i -s -f /odbc.ini -l
RUN cat /etc/odbc.ini
```

Followed instructions [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux) and [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install). on configuration and installation respectively.